# cannot mount vmware tools cdrom in VMware Player

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, vmware-tools

Yes I know, there is another thread but I have another issue.

I am using Windows 7 as host and debian 8 as client.
I have configured a cdrom device in VM-Ware config and I have choosen the debian-8-net-installer.iso image to be inserted by default.

When I try to install vmware tools the default vmware player advice appears which is telling me to mount the cdrom device.

So I type `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom`. After doing `cd /mnt/cdrom` and `ls` i see the content of the default inserted debian-8-net-installer.iso! Not the content of the VM-Ware-Tools image.

Is anybody out there who is able to tell me whats wrong and what should I do to install vmware tools? I am using Vmware Player 6.0.7 build-2844087.

Answer (score 0):

To install VMware Tools in a Linux guest operating system using Compiler:

1.Ensure that your Linux virtual machine is powered on.

2.If you are running a GUI interface, open a command shell.

Note: Log in as a root user, or use the sudo command to complete each of these steps.

3.Click VM in the virtual machine menu, then click Guest > Install/Upgrade VMware Tools.

4.Click OK.

Note: In some cases, verify that the CDROM device is Connected from within the Edit Settings option of the virtual machine.

5.To create a mount point, run:

> mkdir /mnt/cdrom

6.To mount the CDROM, run:

> mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom

7.To copy the Compiler gzip tar file to a temporary local directory, run:

> cp /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-version.tar.gz /tmp/

Where version is the VMware Tools package version.

8.To determine the version of VMware tools, run:

> ls /mnt/cdrom

You see output similar to:

> ## VMwareTools-5.0.0-12124.tar.gz

9.To change to the tmp directory and extract the contents of the tar file into a new directory called vmware-tools-distrib, run:

> cd /tmp
>
> tar -zxvf VMwareTools-version.tar.gz

10.To change directory to vmware-tools-distrib and run the vmware-install.pl PERL script to install VMware Tools, run:

> cd vmware-tools-distrib
>
> ./vmware-install.pl

Notes:

- Complete the screen prompts to install the VMware Tools. Options in
  square brackets are default choices and can be selected by pressing
  Enter.
- To compile VMware Tools successfully, you need gcc Compiler and Linux
  Kernel sources provided by your Linux distribution. Consult your
  Linux distribution documentation for details on methods to install
  these packages.
- It is normal for the console screen to go blank for a short time
  during the installation when the display size changes.
- Some warnings or errors are normal, like when a files does not exist.
- Depending on the Linux distribution, your network service might
  restart after installation. VMware recommends that you invoke this
  command from the console and not remotely.

11.If you are running a GUI interface, restart your X Window session for any mouse or graphics changes to take effect.

12.To start VMware Tools running in the background during an X Window session, run:

> /usr/bin/vmware-toolbox &

13.Depending on your environment, you may need to unmount the CD-ROM. To unmount the CD-ROM, run:

> umount /mnt/cdrom

14.Depending on your environment, you may need to manually end the VMware Tools installation. To end the VMware Tools install, click VM in the virtual machine menu, then click Guest > End VMware Tools Install.

15.To remove VMware Tools installation packages, run:

> cd
>
> rm /tmp/VMwareTools-version.tar.gz
>
> rm -rf /tmp/vmware-tools-distrib

From [VMware kb](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018414)

Comment: yes. thank you very much but i already know all of this and did it several times before. But now i have the issue that there is no content of vmwaretools in my cdrom and i dont know why.

Comment: so step 7 failes because there is no vmware tools in my cdrom. the mouted cdrom shows the content of my iso file configured in vmware player settings although i have choosen install vmware tools option from menu.